# Figma tag says it's OK to ask graphic design questions here

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-wiki

The [figma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/figma) tag says:

> Ask anything related to designing graphics and interfaces with Figma.

Since it's an "interface design tool", it's not programming related and it should be clarified so as not to indicate that asking graphic design questions here is OK.

Comment: Just to have an easy point of reference: there is a [tag:figma-api], so, regardless of the discussion outcome, we should probably take a look if questions tagged [tag:figma] belong there instead.

Comment: I also think that most questions that are not directly about Figma API can find a good home on [Web Apps StackExchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). As for questions that use the tag to signify that the OP uses Figma, but is actually about design, I think they use the tag as a meta tag.

Comment: So...why didn't you just edit it? I'm not trying to get on your case about it. I'm actually wondering. The current tag excerpt content (now edited) seems like a fairly typical example of the sort of thing that creeps into tag excerpts and wikis, which should then be edited to make the usage clear.

Comment: @Makyen Why not merge into [figma-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/figma-api)? Every [figma]-question I see is either off-topic, falsely tagged or api-related

Comment: @leonheess Because, that's not what was requested here, so I didn't look into it. I'm also not familiar with Figma, so don't have an immediate opinion.